# Ubuntu server 13.04 ssh keygen issue

Tags: 13.04, server, ssh

I want to be able to use github and their service hooks to deploy sites and apps to the server.

To do this I need to create an ssh key and put the public key into github.

I go through the `ssh-keygen` process on the Ubuntu server and it says that the key has been generated and saved in `/home/'myusername'/id_something` I can't remember. But when I open that file with nano it is an empty file.

Googling that problem brings up one person with a similar problem who said it was caused by there being too many processes running that it couldn't write to the file but this is a brand new server with 80 GB disk, 2 GB RAM and 2 core processor and it has literally nothing else running.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the correct filename to nano? if you made a typo then you would get an empty file. FWIW the default location for the public key file (assuming you generated an rsa key) would be /home/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or equivalently ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (note the .ssh part is a hidden directory, to see it in the ordinary file manager you will need to unhide it either via the menu or Ctrl-h)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My apologies yes the path I said was incorrect the file is in the home/usrname/.ssh/ and the file name is id_rsa.  I jsut opened it again taking care to spell it correctly and it is definitely empty.

Comment: I was following a tutorial to do this that had me create this file myself in advance of the keygen process.  might the process have saved it somewhere else as a result?  Are there any keys that are set up when you install the server?  if so can these just be used instead of creating new ones?

Comment: AFAIK the install process (for OpenSSH at least) only creates host keys - not the personal key pair that you are trying to create here. If you haven't actually deployed the key anywhere, there's really no downside to just running 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' a second time (it will just overwrite the previous key, if it finds it in the same location)